# VirtualizedList: missing keys for items - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-listview

On my `componentDidMount()` I do a Query where I receive some documents from a MongoDb database which I want to show in a `FlatList`. When I have received the results from the Query I map them to my `state.list` with the function `mapToList()` The `list.id` I use here is an inserted document `_id` generated by MongoDb itself. Just to have a `id` to work with here. Then I add `key={item.id}` to my `renderItem({item})` method, but I still get the error that I have to add keys to my VirtualizedList or use a KeyExtractor.

I'm trying to delete an item from the `FlatList` with the use of `Swipeout` but first I have to get this `id` thing to work.

```
export default class MyFlatList extends React.Component{
 state={   
 loading: false,
 list: [{
   name: '',
   subtitle: '',
   rightSubtitle: '',
   rightTitle: '',
   id: undefined
 }]
};
```

### mapToList();

```
mapToList(result)
{ 
  const list = [];
  for(var i = 0; i<result.length; i++)
  {
      list[i] =  {name: result[i].name,
      subtitle : result[i].projectname,
      rightTitle : result[i].work,
      rightSubtitle : result[i].date,
      id: result[i]._id
    };
  }
  this.setState({list});
}
```

### render()

```
  render(){
  return(
    <View>
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.list}
      renderItem={this.renderItem}
      />
      <ActivityIndicator animating={this.state.loading} color="black" size="large"/>
    </View>
        )
  }
```

### renderItem({item})

```
renderItem = ({item}) => (
  <Swipeout right={swipeoutBtns}>
  <ListItem
    title={item.name}
    key={item.id}
    titleStyle={styles.titleText}
    subtitleStyle={styles.subtitleText}
    rightTitleStyle={styles.rightSubtitleText}
    rightSubtitleStyle={styles.rightSubtitleText}
    rightIcon={
      <Icon name="keyboard-arrow-right"
          size={17}
          color="black"
        />}
    subtitle={item.subtitle}
    rightTitle={item.rightTitle}
    rightSubtitle={item.rightSubtitle}
    leftAvatar={{rounded:false, title:'PS'}}
  />
  </Swipeout>
)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need `keyExtractor` parameter. As default it will check if the item has a `key` property which you don't that why you are getting this warning.

> Used to extract a unique key for a given item at the specified index. Key is used for caching and as the react key to track item re-ordering. The default extractor checks item.key, then falls back to using the index, like React does.

Do this:

```
 _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id.toString();

<FlatList
   data={this.state.list}
   renderItem={this.renderItem}
   keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
 />
```

Comment: This is correct but put `item.id.toString()` since key needs to be string

Comment: @fayeed @crodev I've tried this, but it's still giving me the same error. I specified a `key={item.id}` for each `ListItem` in the `renderItem({item})` method. What is than the difference between this and the `KeyExtractor` approach?

Comment: I don't quite know the difference but sometimes when I was working with flat lists, `keyExtractor` worked but `key` didn't

Comment: FlatList as default checks to see if the item has a `key` property if yes assign it if not it will use the index of the item. `keyExtractor` is used to override the default behavior since the key is your `id` property. As for your case when you assign a `key` property manually during `renderItem` it gets override by the default `keyExtractor` function.

Comment: When I removed the `key` from my `ListItem` and used the `keyExtractor` it worked!

Comment: Using exact this form and still get same error, so then seems a bug in the error catching

Comment: using keyExtractor={item => item.key}
        renderItem={({ item, key })=>{  // element to render let me have this know error that in this case should not be "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop"